# Keep The Row Value Same After Filtering. (Google App script, Spreadsheet)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

(SITUATION)

I have have bunch of data in my table with a button at the end of column for each row.
The data is from Spreadsheet table and I showing the table in Modal dialogue.
So whenever I clicked the button in the table, the program will get the that row to run/.setValue() in Google Spreadsheet according to the row. So if the button is in row 1, it will run/.setValue() row 1 in Spreadsheet as well.

(PROBLEM)

Now if I make filter function in modal dialogue and filter it based in name for example, few row will missing right. After filtering the table(let's say row 3 become row number 1), whenever I clicked the button, it will run the first row in Spreadsheet but it suppose to run row 3.

(QUESTION)

So the question is how to keep the row value the same even after I filtered it?

(MY CODE GS GET TABLE)

```
function getTable(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Query_Script");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  Logger.log(data);
  return {'success': true,'data':data};
}


function getRow(row,column){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Query_Script");
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var dataValue = dataRange.getDisplayValues();

  //Execute when clicked approved button.
  var value = sheet.getRange(row+1,10).setValue("Approved");

    var scriptLastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
      for(var j=1; j<scriptLastRow; j++){
        var applyLdap = sheet.getRange(j+1,3).getValue();
      }
    //Sheet ROTA :
        var ssRota = ss.getSheetByName("ROTA");
        var rotaLastRow = ssRota.getLastRow();

        var getLdap = sheet.getRange(row + 1 , 3).getValue();

          for(var x=11; x<sheet.getLastColumn(); x++){
            //Changing col to row:
            var ldapIndex = ssRota.getRange(1,4,rotaLastRow,1).getValues();//highlight ldap column
            var ldapRow = ldapIndex.map(function(row){return row[0];});//changing from column to row
            var ldap = ldapRow.indexOf(getLdap)+1;//find ldap
            var getCol = sheet.getRange(row+1,x).getValue();//value=6,7
            
            Logger.log(ldap);
            Logger.log(getCol);
      //stop execute if no value:
        if(getCol === ""){
          false;

        }else if(getCol === 9 || getCol === 10){
          ssRota.getRange(ldap,getCol).setValue("L");

        }else if(getCol % 7 === 2 || getCol % 7 === 3){
          ssRota.getRange(ldap,getCol).setValue("L");
          
        }
        else{
          ssRota.getRange(ldap,getCol).setValue("V");
        }
    }
}
```

(MY CODE HTML FOR TABLE)

```
window.onload = function (){
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getTable();
      }

      function onSuccess(data){
        if(data.success){
        //console.log(data.data);//{application array(4), success:true}&&[array(27),Array(27)]
        var html = '<table>';
        var row;
        for(var i=0; i<data.data.length; i++){
          html += '<tr>';
          row = i;
          console.log(row);//[0,1,2,3,]
            for (var j=0; j<9; j++){
              html += '<td>'+ data.data[i][j]+'</td>';
            }
            html += '<td>'+ '<button data-row="'+i+'" data-column="'+j+'" id="btn">Approved</button>'+'</td>';
            html += '</tr>';
          }
          html += '</table>';
          output.innerHTML = html;
          //console.log(data);//{data:Array(4), success:true}
          const table = document.querySelector("table");
          table.addEventListener('click',approve);
        }
      }

      function approve(e){
        const td = e.target;
        const [row, column] = [parseInt(td.dataset.row),parseInt(td.dataset.column)];
        console.log(td);
        console.log([row,column]);
        google.script.run.getRow(row,column);
        
        const table = document.querySelectorAll("button");
        table[row].style.backgroundColor = "red";
      }
```

(GS CODE FILTER)

```
function myFilter(ldap) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Query_Script");
  var originalData = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow(),10).getValues();
  var testData = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  var getLdap = ldap;

  var dataAgent = testData.filter(function(info){return info[0] === "Email Address" || info[2] === ldap;});

  return dataAgent;

}
```

```
ldap.onchange = function(){
          console.log(this.value);
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showFilter).myFilter(this.value);
        }
      
        function showFilter(dataAgent){
          console.log(dataAgent);

          var html = '<table>';
          var row;
            for(var i=0; i<dataAgent.length; i++){
          html += '<tr>';
          row = i;
          console.log(row);//[0,1,2,3,]
            for (var j=0; j<9; j++){
              html += '<td>'+ dataAgent[i][j]+'</td>';
            }
            html += '<td>'+ '<button data-row="'+i+'" data-column="'+j+'" id="btn">Approved</button>'+'</td>';
            html += '</tr>';
          }
          html += '</table>';
          output.innerHTML = html;
          
          const table = document.querySelector("table");
          table.addEventListener('click',approve);
        }
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `Now if I make filter function in modal dialogue and filter it based in name for example, few row will missing right. After filtering the table(let's say row 3 become row number 1), whenever I clicked the button, it will run the first row in Spreadsheet but it suppose to run row 3.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: @Tanaike yes sorry for my explanation.

What I mean is I create a table in Modal dialogue, and the data I took from Google Spread sheet. I added one button at the last column in each row so every time I click the button the data will send back information and tell me which row the button is. For example, I click button at row 1, and it will console.log row 1. Now if I add filter function to it, and filter the data, let say row 1 we have John Doe, row 2 we have Mr. Smith, if I filter to Mr.Smith, the table will only show Mr.smith data right?

Comment: So now Mr.Smith data will be the first row in that filtered table. Now when I click the button at Mr Smith row, it return to me as row 1 not row 2. What I want is whenever I click the button, the button should return as the exact previous row which for this case it should return row 2. I think the problem is with my code, because i filter the data from Google spreadsheet which make sense why iy return as row 1 but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: @Tanaike Actually I'm making a leave application system. So if I clicked the button, it will approve and update something in the system. Agent using Google Form which will transfer in Spreadsheet. If there are too many application, I need to filter it so I know which one should I approve first. And thats what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, from your replying, I couldn't still understand about your current issue and your goal.

Comment: @Tanaike it's okay. I already found a solution for the issue.

Comment: If you found a solution for your issue, would you mind posting an answer? This could help other people who might be experiencing a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. Basically instead of filter data in google spreadsheet and extract data back to Modal dialogue, I just created new table and assign value to each button directly in modal dialogue.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){

    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(generateTable).getTableData();

});

function generateTable(dataArray){

  dataArray.forEach(function(r){

    var row = document.createElement("tr");


    var col1 = document.createElement("td");
      col1.textContent = r[1];
    var col2 = document.createElement("td");
      col2.textContent = r[2];
    var col7 = document.createElement("button");
      const getRow = table.rows.length;
      col7.innerHTML = "Approve";
      col7.setAttribute("class",getRow)

    row.appendChild(col1);
    row.appendChild(col2);
    row.appendChild(col3);

    tbody.appendChild(row);
```

getTableData() is just GS code that take data from Spreadsheet.
Then I start filter it:

```
name.onchange = function(){
        
     for(var i=1; i<table.rows.length; i++){
          if(table.rows[i].cells[0].textContent === this.value){
            console.log(table.rows[i].cells[0].textContent);
            table.rows[i].style.display = "";

          }else{
            table.rows[i].style.display = "none";
          }
      }
  }
```

So now whenever I filter it and click the button, the button will return row index and update that particular row in Spreadsheet.